# Unable to start ios simulator of libgdx

Tags: java, ios, android-studio, libgdx

I'm using [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) in Android Studio, i can run Android and Desktop Launcher of my project properly, but run IOSLauncher makes this error :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.robovm.rt.VM.getStackClasses(II)[Ljava/lang/Class;
at org.robovm.rt.VM.getStackClasses(Native Method)
at org.robovm.rt.bro.Bro.bind(Bro.java:50)
at org.robovm.objc.ObjCRuntime.<clinit>(ObjCRuntime.java:43)
at org.robovm.objc.ObjCObject.<clinit>(ObjCObject.java:55)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)
```

and i can't run IOS simulator of libgdx properly.

Comment: iOS app can be run in simulator under MacOS only. Do you run it under MacOS?

Comment: @Rara libgdx uses robovm, and in its tutorials its iOS simulator works in Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS Simulator doesn't work in Windows or Linux. You can check it in official [libGDX documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-%28Eclipse%2C-Intellij-IDEA%2C-NetBeans%29) (or in [RoboVM documentation](http://www.robovm.com/develop/documentation/)):

> To additionally target iOS
>
> - A Mac, iOS Development does not work on Windows/Linux thanks to Apple.
> - The latest XCode, which you can get from the Mac OS X App Store for free

You can use virtual machine with MacOS X to fulfill these requirements (like I do).